# ReactJS - Unsure of how to get item to redirect to external link

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a new portfolio site for the first time in React. I've come across an issue where I'd like to include links to external pages from stills of portfolio work. They way I've tried to work it is by having a data.js file which consists of the portfolio items but I'm looking to wrap a link around the returned item but I'm receiving errors:

data.js code:

```
export const featuredPortfolio = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Social Media App",
      img:
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKvdHn8GmPGCO0y3SJqNHACygpm0h9VycMHg&usqp=CAU",
        url: "https://www.google.com",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Rampa UI Design",
      img:
        "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/702789/screenshots/15054318/media/4ea5d492b7b07eebc9528ff960794879.png?compress=1&resize=1200x900",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "E-commerce Web Design",
      img:
        "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1387827/screenshots/15466426/media/deb2dca6762cd3610321c98bfccb0b72.png?compress=1&resize=1200x900",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Relax Mobile App",
      img:
        "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/4095861/screenshots/15467417/media/d6a15c416626f12b31fa5ca1db192572.png?compress=1&resize=1200x900",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "Hero Web Design",
      img:
        "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/5031392/screenshots/15467520/media/c36b3b15b25b1e190d081abdbbf947cf.png?compress=1&resize=1200x900",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: "Banking App",
      img:
        "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3307260/screenshots/15468444/media/447b4501f7a145b05e11c70199a9c417.jpg?compress=1&resize=1200x900",
    },
  ];
```

Portfolio.jsx code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PortfolioList from "../portfoliolist/portfoliolist";
import "./portfolio.scss";
import {
  featuredPortfolio,
  webPortfolio,
  mobilePortfolio,
} from "../../data";
import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Portfolio() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("featured");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const list = [
    {
      id: "featured",
      title: "Featured",
    },
    {
      id: "web",
      title: "Web App",
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (selected) {
      case "featured":
        setData(featuredPortfolio);
        break;
      case "web":
        setData(webPortfolio);
        break;
      case "mobile":
        setData(mobilePortfolio);
        break;
      default:
        setData(featuredPortfolio);
    }
  }, [selected]);

  return (
    <div className="portfolio" id="portfolio">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      <ul>
        {list.map((item) => (
          <PortfolioList
            title={item.title}
            active={selected === item.id}
            setSelected={setSelected}
            id={item.id}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div className="container">
        {data.map((d) => (
          <div className="item">
            <img
              src={d.img}
              alt=""
            />
            <h3>{d.title}</h3>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any pointers would be very helpful - thank you!

Comment: you want the images to be shown in a new tab(redirect to a new tab)?

Answer (score 0):

Add an a tag inside of the map function, make the href a  link to the external url

```
<a href={d.url}> Visit site </a>
```

To make it open in a new tab add

```
<a href={d.url} target="_blank" > Visit site </a>
```